# Command + Tab not working properly on Magic Keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, monterey, text-editor

I am using an external Magic Keyboard to code on a text editor. Currently I am using the VS Code.

I need to frequently switch applications and for that I use a shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Whenever I am on the text editor the tabs do the switch when I press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> but apart from switching applications, the lines get cut in the text editor.

I tried looking up the shortcuts on VS code but there is no Cut command with shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. However, when I use the internal keyboard the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works fine as lines do not get cut when <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed. This behaviour is consistent along all text editors.

I am using macOS Monterey 12.2.1.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Ok so there might be a confusion I meant to switch applications not tabs. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Take it to the genius bar. The keyboard may be defective, with a mechanical issue or internal short that sends a signal for the 'C' key when you press the Command key. Have you spilled anything on it?

Comment: Haven't spilled anything on it. It's the magic keyboard that is causing trouble not the internal keybaord.

Comment: Also this behaviour is only seen while switching from a text editor to another app so I am pretty sure the keyboard is fine.

Comment: A magic keyboard has internal circuitry too, so spilling something on it can cause problems. Doesn't have to be on the computer. But that being said, have you tested with another app for which ⌘C is meaningful? A graphics app, say, or a browser with a text field active? You won't see a cut from an app that doesn't support cuts.

Comment: Makes sense even when switching between applications while URL is highlighted the URL gets cut. Seems like an hardware issue will get it checked thanks for the assistance.

Comment: You could try [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) & see what it's actually sending

Comment: Command + Tab is sending Command + X

Comment: & does Tab alone send X? Test the rest of the keyboard & see if what it's sending is generally right or wrong. It might just be one key, but if it's just one combo that's weird, idk what might be causing it, unless you had Karabiner on there at some point, or perhaps Ukelele. Try changing input language & see what happens.

Comment: No Tab alone does not sends X. Reset of the keyboard works fine. `Cmd` + `Tab` is sending `Cmd`+`X`. I tested same combination using `Cmd` on the right of space and that works fine.

Comment: Unless you have Karabiner running, all I could suggest is test that keyboard on another Mac & another keyboard on that Mac.